# Place Twitter Widget to Right of Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML and am making a simple one page website and want to add the twitter widget but when I add the widget it goes below my form.  Is there a way to make it go to the right of the page as well as adjust the width of the twitter widget.  The code for the webpage is below.

http://codepad.org/QcPq5Xur

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the form inside it's own div container.

Set a specific width to this div of the amount of space on the left you want it to take up.

Create another new div, and insert the twitter feed script inside of this.

Set a specific width if desired to set an absolute width to it, or a percentage. If you don't set a width it should fill any extra space not used by the div containing the form.

As long as the width of the two divs is less than than the width of the browser area, they will display side by side. You could also wrap the two in another div containing a minimum width if you wanted them to be forced side by side no matter browser resolution.

Answer (score 0):

that's because your form is wrapped with `div` which is a block level element. Try altering its display to `inline-block`

```
<div id="formContainer" style='text-align: center; display: inline-block;'>
    <a name="form789985197" id="formAnchor789985197"></a>
</div>
```